# Migrate IAMs Users, Roles and Groups to another aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to migrate all iam users, roles and groups to another aws account.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are `terraforming` and `terraform apply`

#### terraforming

Export existing AWS resources to Terraform style (tf, tfstate)

```
  terraforming iamg            # IAM Group
  terraforming iamgm           # IAM Group Membership
  terraforming iamgp           # IAM Group Policy
  terraforming iamip           # IAM Instance Profile
  terraforming iamp            # IAM Policy
  terraforming iamr            # IAM Role
  terraforming iamrp           # IAM Role Policy
  terraforming iamu            # IAM User
  terraforming iamup           # IAM User Policy
```

http://terraforming.dtan4.net/

https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming

#### terraform

Terraform is hashicorp's product, you can apply the resources, such as IAM, directly with simple template.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_group.html#

https://www.terraform.io/intro/index.html

Comment: you can also use [cloudformer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) its an AWS product that will create cloud formation template that you can reuse in your other account -

Comment: You should answer it, but I am not the fan of `cloudformation`

Comment: I may be reading too much into the question, but it sounds like OP wants to migrate users with their keys intact.  This seems like it would be more like structural duplication... which is fair enough, since actual "migration" wouldn't be possible.